# How to read in integers from a file in Java

Tags: java

Okay so I wanted to read in the integers I have along with the strings in a file. So far I have this code and I keep getting an error. I have this in my text file: Grey:30
Black:40
I'm trying to read in the strings along with the integers because I want to set the integers as points worth for the string (color)

```
while (strike!=3){  
             Scanner name1 = new Scanner(System.in);      
             System.out.println("Enter A color");
             String nameTaken = name1.next();

         while(filechecker.hasNextLine()){
             list.add(filechecker.nextLine());
         }
         String line =filechecker.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split(":");//checks for the integer next to the color
         if((list.contains(nameTaken))&&(filechecker.hasNextInt())){
             int points = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
                  System.out.println("The Answer Exists!! You Got " +details[2]);
```

Comment: What error do you keep getting?

Comment: You seem to have a loop that eats up all the next lines, then calls next line one more time, when it's guaranteed to fail.  What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: Also, `String line =filechecker.nextLine();` will probably not work the way you think, since you just came out of a while-loop that consumed all lines in that `Scanner`.

Comment: *Just a tip:* If you are sure that the file will always have the structure "string:integer" you can use the `split(":")` method to separate the string from the integer. Maybe it will be more easily to handle.

Comment: I keep getting this error:      Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Answer (score 2):

You don't indicate what error you're getting, but I can see from the following code, you're likely getting a `NullPointerException` or something similar.

**Edit**: Seems you're getting the `NoSuchElementException` because no lines remain to be read.

This block of code loops through your `filechecker` and reads all lines into a list, until no more lines remain. The line immediately following the while block attempts to read another line from it, which it won't find because you've read them all (it will return `null`). The line where you try to `split` will throw an exception because of this.

```
while(filechecker.hasNextLine()){
     list.add(filechecker.nextLine());
}
String line =filechecker.nextLine();  // <-- this line is throwing it. Don't use it here, use your list or do your work in the while loop instead.
String[] details = line.split(":");//checks for the integer next to the color
```

Instead of operating on the `filechecker` after your while, loop, use your list. Or better yet, do all your work *in* the while loop instead.

Comment: Thank you and I understand what you're saying but I then get I an error for having the "line" not resolved. I guess I got error there because it's outside the loop. Sorry but I'm kind of new to java

Comment: I don't know what you're changing your code to, so I can't say... but if you iterate through the list you create, you can assign line using a `foreach` loop. `for(String line : list) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a HashMap to store your data:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> colorData = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

You can then use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream to write and read the file:

```
void write(String fileName) {
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
  out.writeObject(colorData);
}

void read(String fileName) {
  ObjectInputStream in = null;
  try {
    fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    colorData = (HashMap<String, Integer>) in.readObject();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }finally {
    if(objectinputstream != null)
      objectinputstream .close();
  } 
}
```